# Is it possible to invert the clipping of SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a rectangle on an SVG element. I then want to draw another rectangle over the whole SVG area *except* the rect I've already drawn.

I thought masks might be a solution but they seem to act just like clipping - doing the *inverse* of what I want. I've tried this:

```
<svg id="mySVG" width="600" height="250">
    <defs>
        <mask id="myMask" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="250" >
            <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="white"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="250" fill="red" mask="url(#myMask)"></rect>
</svg>
```

So what I'm after is the inverse of this image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Draw a rect for the whole thing then use a black circle to cut out the whole.

Or alternatively and more performantly, draw the whole thing with a path wherein you can draw the rect clockwise and the circle anticlockwise as a cut-out.

Here's the easiest first option given that you are already most of the way there with that one.

```html
 <svg id="mySVG" width="600" height="250">
    <defs>
        <mask id="myMask" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="250" >
            <rect width="600" height="250" fill="white"/>
            <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="black"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="250" fill="red" mask="url(#myMask)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, @RobertLongson. I've spent long hours trying to get a `path`-based `clipPath` or `mask` to cut a hole in a `<rect>` and your example above was the first I successfully got to work with my own setup. I think a key consideration - which almost no-one ever seems to mention - is that if the `mask` element is very pale or white (my `path` was white), it _won't be visible_. Your example showed me that not only should my `path` not be white - it should be black. I only understand now that the colours of the mask elements matter a great deal when trying to cut out shapes from other shapes.